# JSON into Model extension

Tags: swift, realm, swifty-json

I have the following class which i'd like to write an extension method for to easily serialize my JSON into.

```
class Evaluation: Object {
    var name: String?
    var isFinalized: Bool?
    var id: Int?
    var idString: String? {
        get{
            return String(describing:self.id!)
        }
    }

    convenience init(json: JSON?) {
        self.init()
        if let json = json {
            name = json["evaluationDescription"].rawString()
            isFinalized = json["evaluationFinalized"].intValue == 0 ? false : true
            id = json["evaluationID"].intValue
        }
    }

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
}
```

This is the extension i wrote, but i'd like for it to be mutating and more globally usable.  So that i can use the same code for all my models.

```
extension Evaluation {
    func serialize(from json: JSON){
        var temp = [Evaluation]()
        for (_,j): (String,JSON) in json {
            temp.append(Evaluation(json: j))
        }
    }
}
```

I tried making the method `mutating`, but got an error

> 'mutating' is not valid on methods in classes...

In summary, i'd like to use it like so (json is somewhat pseudo code)...

```
var json = "{'name':'test','isFinalized','0','id':'532'}"

var evaluations = [Evaluations]()
evaluations.serialize(from: json)
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4 has a new protocol called Codable. If you want your class be serializable you just need to make this protocol be adopted by your class. Like this:

```
class Evaluation: Object, Codable {
    var name: String?
    var isFinalized: Bool?
    var id: Int?
    var idString: String? {
        get{
            return String(describing:self.id!)
        }
    }
}
```

Since all your properties are from Swift Standard Library, your class is ready to be serialized with `JSONEncoder` type.

```
let evaluation = Evaluation()
let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(evaluation)
```

and decoded like this:

```
let decoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Evaluation.self, encoded)
```

Since this protocol automatically makes your class serializable, you don't need that initializers, so it can be like this:

```
class Evaluation: Object, Codable {
    var name: String
    var isFinalized: Bool
    var id: Int
    var idString: String {
        get{
            return String(describing:self.id!)
        }
    }
}
```

Moreover, if your models don't need to be a class, make it a struct. Structs use less computation to be instantiated and is more [Value Type Oriented Programming](https://www.google.com.br/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjBy5H4yqDXAhVGYVAKHcCZC1gQtwIIOjAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.apple.com%2Fvideos%2Fplay%2Fwwdc2016%2F419%2F&usg=AOvVaw2ElLMe7u_ZTL7CufaTLbPi).

For more information about this, please visit [Swift Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types).

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I will give that a try, however, i'm using Realm, so i have to use initializers or default values.

Comment: Just a quick note; structs are a good idea in many cases but Realm model types have to be classes.

Answer (score 0):

protocol JSONable {   init?(parameter: JSON) }

//MARK:- JSON
extension JSON
{ func to(type: T?) -> Any?  {  if let baseObj = type as?  JSONable.Type  { if self.type == .array {   var arrObject: [Any] = []  arrObject = self.arrayValue.map  {  baseObj.init(parameter: $0)!  } return arrObject  }   else  { let object = baseObj.init(parameter: self) return object!   }  }  return nil } }

Comment: Please edit your answer to format code appropriately.

Comment: And you should provide an explanation as to what it’s doing.